# Function that gets one number out of two possible numbers (4 or 7) and returns the the second number

Tags: c, algorithm

I have to implement a function that gets one of two numbers: 4 or 7.
The function must return the second number **without use of arithmetic operations**, for example:

If the function gets **4** as argument - it returns **7**,

if the function gets **7** as argument - it returns **4**.

I look for a solution other than the obvious `return x==7?4:7`

It is possible that the solution addresses the binary representation properties of these numbers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since 4 is `100` in binary and 7 is `111`, you just have to XOR the input with 3 (`11`).

This way, `100 xor 011 = 111` and `111 xor 011 == 100`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit underspecified, what shoudl we return if we're passed (say) 11, 12 or 4711? Below is a function that returns the expected results for 4 and 7, but returns -1 for any of the non-specified cases.

```
/* Returns 4, if passed 7, 7 if passed 4. 
 * If passed a number not 4 or 7, returns -1
 */
int f(int x)
{
  switch (x) {
    case 4: return 7;
    case 7: return 4;
    default: return -1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Arithmetic:

```
int f(int x){
  return 11-x;
}
```

Using Map:

```
Map<int, int> dictionary = new HashMap();
dictionary.put(4,7);
dictionary.put(7,4);

int f(int x){
 return dictionary.get(x);
}
```